# Pass a Parameter to an onClick Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onclicklistener, single-page-application

I created a React single page application with the API from the NASA Picture of the Day and I added in a drawer a list with the history of the images displayed and it's is showing only its dates.

I have a Material-UI list item and I want to pass to its `onClick` function a parameter. I want that when I click on a specific date on the drawer to show me the image from that specific date.

Here I want to pass the parameter index:

```
pushDate = () => {
    menu.dates.push(this.state.image.date);
    index = menu.dates.indexOf(this.state.image.date);  
    menu.menuItems.push(
        <List>
            <ListItem onClick={this.handleClose} primaryText={this.state.image.date} leftIcon={<ImagePhoto />} />
        </List>
    );  
}
```

And here is the handleClose function :

```
handleClose = (date) => {
    this.setState({
        open: false,
        controlledDate: moment(menu.dates[index]),
    });
    this.getImage(moment(menu.dates[index]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `onClick={() => this.handleClose(this.state.image.date)}`